# how to move an image from folder and resize before saving to another folder?

Tags: php

I am working on a project which multiple pages validation. My main issue is with the upload part of the code. What i am doing is when a user upload his images; i save them in a tempfolder then once form filled complete, i move the images from temp to mainfolder but before i want to resize the images before saving them in mainfolder.

How can i achieve that ?

I have tried myself but could not get it right.here is my code

i got this error : `getimagesize(174349.jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory`

**imageuploaded.php**

```
<?php
define('MAX_FILE_SIZE', 952070);
define('UPLOAD_DIR_TEMP', BASE_URI.'html/temp/');
$max = number_format(MAX_FILE_SIZE/1024, 1).'KB';
// create an array of permitted MIME types
$permitted = array('image/gif', 'image/jpeg', 'image/pjpeg','image/png');   

  if (array_key_exists('upload', $_POST)) {
foreach ($_FILES['image']['name'] as $number => $file) {
// replace any spaces in the filename with underscores
$file = str_replace(' ','_',$file);
$fileNom = pathinfo($_FILES['image']["name"][$number], PATHINFO_FILENAME);
$ext = pathinfo($_FILES['image']["name"][$number],PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
//$soruceimg = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
//echo $file;
// begin by assuming the file is unacceptable
$sizeOK = false;
$typeOK = false;
// check that file is within the permitted size
if ($_FILES['image']['size'][$number] > 0 || $_FILES['image']['size'][$number] <= MAX_FILE_SIZE) {
$sizeOK = true;
}
// check that file is of a permitted MIME type
foreach ($permitted as $type) {
if ($type == $_FILES['image']['type'][$number]) {
$typeOK = true;
break;
}
}

if ($sizeOK && $typeOK) {
switch($_FILES['image']['error'][$number]) {
case 0:

// get the date and time
ini_set('date.timezone', 'Africa/Abidjan');
$now = date('Y-m-d-His');
//$Nfilename = basename(substr($file,0,6).$now).".".$ext ." ";
$successes = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'][$number], UPLOAD_DIR_TEMP.$file);
if ($successes) {
$_SESSION['imgname']= $_FILES['image']['name'];
header('Location: test.php');
    //echo $file;
}
else {
$resultfile[] = "Error uploading $file. Please try again.";
}
break;
case 3:
$resultfile[] = "Error uploading $file. Please try again.";
default:
$resultfile[] = "System error uploading $file. Contact webmaster.";
}
}
elseif ($_FILES['image']['error'][$number] == 4) {
$errNofile[] = 1;
}
else {
$resultfile[] = "$file cannot be uploaded. Maximum size: $max.Acceptable file types: gif, jpg, png.";
}

}
}
```

**imageresize.php**

```
$source = BASE_URI.'html/temp/';
define('THUMBS_DIR', BASE_URI.'html/products/thumbs/');
define('MAX_WIDTH', 200);
define('MAX_HEIGHT', 200);
define('UPLOAD_DIR', BASE_URI.'html/products/');
ini_set('date.timezone', 'Africa/Abidjan');
$now = date('Y-m-d-His');
 if (isset($_SESSION['imgname']) && is_array($_SESSION['imgname']) ) {

  foreach ($_SESSION['imgname'] as $files) {
  echo $files;
  $img = str_replace(" ", "_", $files);
  $ext = pathinfo($img,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

   if (file_exists($source.$img)) {
    $ext = pathinfo($img,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    // strip the extension off the image filename
   $imagetypes = array('/\.gif$/', '/\.jpg$/', '/\.jpeg$/', '/\.png$/');
   $name = preg_replace($imagetypes, '', basename(substr($img,0,6).$now));

   list($width, $height, $type) = getimagesize($img);
   if ($width != $height) {
     echo "file width and height must be same";
     break;
    }
      elseif ( $width < 300 && $height < 300) {
        echo "File must be at least 400 x 400";
        break;
      }
      else{
        $ratio = 1;
        $ratio = MAX_WIDTH/$width;
      }

   $Nfilename = $name.'.'.$ext;
    $moved = rename($source.$img, UPLOAD_DIR.$Nfilename);

  if (!$moved) {
    echo "Problem moving file".$img;
  }
    else{
    // create an image resource for the original
  switch($type) {
      case 1:
        $source = @ imagecreatefromgif($original);
      if (!$source) {
        $result = 'Cannot process GIF files. Please use JPEG or PNG.';
        }
      break;
      case 2:
        $source = imagecreatefromjpeg($original);
      break;
      case 3:
        $source = imagecreatefrompng($original);
      break;
      default:
        $source = NULL;
      $result = 'Cannot identify file type.';
      }

   // make sure the image resource is OK
  if (!$source) {
    $result = 'Problem copying original';
    }
      else {
    // calculate the dimensions of the thumbnail
      $thumb_width = round($width * $ratio);
      $thumb_height = round($height * $ratio);
    // create an image resource for the thumbnail
      $thumb = imagecreatetruecolor($thumb_width, $thumb_height);
    // create the resized copy
    imagecopyresampled($thumb, $source, 0, 0, 0, 0, $thumb_width, $thumb_height, $width, $height);
    // save the resized copy
    switch($type) {
        case 1:
        if (function_exists('imagegif')) {
          $success = imagegif($thumb, THUMBS_DIR.$name.'_thb.gif');
          $thumb_name = $name.'_thb.gif';
        }
        else {
          $success = imagejpeg($thumb, THUMBS_DIR.$name.'_thb.jpg', 50);
        $thumb_name = $name.'_thb.jpg';
        }
        break;
      case 2:
        $success = imagejpeg($thumb, THUMBS_DIR.$name.'_thb.jpg', 100);
        $thumb_name = $name.'_thb.jpg';
        break;
      case 3:
        $success = imagepng($thumb, THUMBS_DIR.$name.'_thb.png');
        $thumb_name = $name.'_thb.png';
      }
    if ($success) {
      $result = "$thumb_name created";
      }
    else {
      $result = 'Problem creating thumbnail';
      }

    if ($success) {
      echo $thumb_name;
    }

    // remove the image resources from memory
    imagedestroy($source);
    imagedestroy($thumb);
    }   
  }

   }
     else{
      echo "No file exist";
     }

  }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert the image to bitmap first and use bitmap compression with defined ratio to compress the size.
you can compress the image by declaring specific height and width also.

Answer (score 0):

I had this code before, very easy to use, it works for me

```
class SimpleImage {   
var $image; var $image_type;   
function load($filename) {   

  $image_info = getimagesize($filename); 

  $this->image_type = $image_info[2]; 

  if( $this->image_type == IMAGETYPE_JPEG ) {  $this->image = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename); } 

  elseif( $this->image_type == IMAGETYPE_GIF ) {  $this->image = imagecreatefromgif($filename); } 

    elseif( $this->image_type == IMAGETYPE_PNG ) {  $this->image = imagecreatefrompng($filename); } 
} 

function save($filename, $image_type=IMAGETYPE_JPEG, $compression=75, $permissions=null) { 

  if( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_JPEG ) { imagejpeg($this->image,$filename,$compression); } 

  elseif( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_GIF ) {   imagegif($this->image,$filename); } 

  elseif( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_PNG ) {   imagepng($this->image,$filename); } 

  if( $permissions != null) {   chmod($filename,$permissions); } 
} 

function output($image_type=IMAGETYPE_JPEG) {   
  if( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_JPEG ) { imagejpeg($this->image); } 
  elseif( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_GIF ) {   imagegif($this->image); } 
  elseif( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_PNG ) {   imagepng($this->image); } 
} 

function getWidth() {   return imagesx($this->image); } 
function getHeight() {   return imagesy($this->image); } 

function resizeToHeight($height) {   
   $ratio = $height / $this->getHeight(); 
   $width = $this->getWidth() * $ratio; $this->resize($width,$height); 
 }   

function resizeToWidth($width) { 
   $ratio = $width / $this->getWidth(); 
   $height = $this->getheight() * $ratio; $this->resize($width,$height); 
 }   

function scale($scale) { $width = $this->getWidth() * $scale/100; 
   $height = $this->getheight() * $scale/100; $this->resize($width,$height); 
 }   

function resize($width,$height) { 
   $new_image = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height); 
   imagecopyresampled($new_image, $this->image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $this->getWidth(), $this->getHeight()); 
   $this->image = $new_image; }   
 }
```

Use it as prev image, and save new image

```
$imageRes = new SimpleImage();
            $imageRes->load($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/upload/' . $image . '.jpg');//prev image
            $imageRes->resizeToWidth(120);
            $imageRes->save($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/upload/' . $image . '.jpg');//new image
```